# How to retrieve Logged user image from SharePoint server?

Tags: asp.net, windows, sharepoint-2010

I need to retrieve image of Windows logged in user.

I checked and found that the image can be found in SharePoint2010 server.

How can I retrieve this image with ASP.NET?

Comment: Where your asp.net web application located? On the same server as SharePoint?
Also you want to get picture url?

Comment: the web application will located on the sharepoint server , but i work on company network so i can access my sharepoint site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web application is located on the same server as SharePoint you can use server object model. Try to use [UserProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) class

Something like this:

```
var objUserProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(PortalContext.Current);
//get current users profile
var profile = objUserProfileManager.GetUserProfile();
//get user image URL
var imageUrl = (string)profile[PropertyConstants.PictureUrl][0];
```

I thing to mention - you need to verify that account under which your web application is running has appropriate permissions to SharePoint to make calls to server object model.

EDIT:
If you are looking for web service approach you can use sharepoint [useprofile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407%28v=office.14%29.ASPX) web service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981571(v=office.12).aspx